# Cairo Dock Unity Search Dialog

Tags: unity, cairo-dock

I am using unity but have decided to use the Cairo Dock. I am wondering if there is a way (command and/or .desktop file) to have an icon on the dock that opens the default unity search overlay (top-left of unity launcher.)

**Edit:** I want to replace the applications menu with this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open unity's dash using cairo dock but the dock comes with its own applications menu, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open it. It has a search box on top which you can use to search with-in the applications menu items.

it is not as powerful as unity dash, doesn't search files etc but better than having nothing at all.